# Importing from GitHub to Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, github

I have actually managed to import a project from GitHub to [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29), but my problem is when I try to run the project it keeps saying fix errors on source files. Now I know that the code should work as the person who wrote this app has it in the Google App store. This keeps happening for me on all the projects I have downloaded.

Are the suggestions to what I am doing wrong?

Thanks for the replies, I am new to the whole programming world, so I am not sure whether or not the project has a build file or not.

As @Andres has said, my initial thought was that it was to do with the JDK/Android development kit being not the same as I have on Eclipse.

A link to the project is https://github.com/glebpopov/Hacker-News-Droid-App.

The first error I get says in the console window

> Unable to resolve target 'android 7'

I also have this example for the beginning of the class Activity Helper:

```
public class ActivityHelper {
    private static final String TAG = "ActivityHelper";
    protected Activity mActivity;
    protected SharedPreferences sharedPref = null;
```

And the error here for the second line of code say:

> String cannot be resolved into a type

The error here for the third line of code says:

> Activity cannot be resolved into a type

And there are plenty more across the whole code.

Comment: Did the projects from Github come with a build file of some kind to use with Maven or Gradle or something? You probably want to use the build tool required for that project to download dependencies and whatever other setup options it has.

Comment: What are the errors exactly? Can you edit them into the question?

Answer (score 0):

Some possible causes are:

1. The version published on GitHub has errors, and is not the same that is published on the google app store.
2. The project has dependencies that have not been resolved, because of your Maven (or similar product) configuration.
3. The jdk and/or android development kit required by the project are not the same as the one you have on your Eclipse